# How can I use Boost.Hana to determine whether a functor has a call operator that can be invoked with a particular template argument?

Tags: c++14, boost-hana

In my application, I want to determine at compile time whether an arbitrary functor type `Func` has a nullary call operator that can be invoked with a given explicit template argument `T`. [Based on a previous SO answer that I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419045/boost-hana-how-to-check-if-function-has-specialisation-for-a-certain-type/35419693), I came up with the following:

```cpp
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

namespace detail 
{
    template <typename T>
    auto can_call = hana::is_valid([](auto &&f) -> 
        decltype(f.template operator()<T>()) { });
}

template <typename Func, typename T>
constexpr auto can_call() ->
    decltype(detail::can_call<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>(
        std::declval<Func>())) { return {}; }

struct foo
{
    template <typename T, typename = 
        std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<T, char>::value>>
    void operator()() const { }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "char: " << can_call<foo, char>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "int: " << can_call<foo, int>() << std::endl;
}
```

I would expect this example to print out:

```
char: 0
int: 1
```

Since the `char` template argument type is explicitly `enable_if`-ed out in `foo`. I've tried the following compilers:

- Apple clang v8.0.0: The example compiles and runs as expected.
- mainline clang v3.9.1+ (via Wandbox): The example compiles and runs as expected.
- mainline clang v3.6.0 - v3.8.1 (via Wandbox): The compiler dies with an internal error.
- g++ 7.0 trunk, 20170410 (via Wandbox): The compilation fails with the following errors:

  ```
  dd.cc: In instantiation of ‘auto detail::can_call<char>’:
  dd.cc:15:14:   required by substitution of ‘template<class Func, class T> constexpr decltype (can_call<typename std::remove_reference<_To>::type>(declval<Func>())) can_call() [with Func = foo; T = char]’
  dd.cc:25:50:   required from here
  dd.cc:10:10: error: ‘auto detail::can_call<char>’ has incomplete type
      auto can_call = hana::is_valid([](auto &&f) -> decltype(f.template operator()<T>()) { });
          ^~~~~~~~
  dd.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
  dd.cc:25:50: error: no matching function for call to ‘can_call<foo, char>()’
      std::cout << "char: " << can_call<foo, char>() << std::endl;
                                                  ^
  dd.cc:14:16: note: candidate: template<class Func, class T> constexpr decltype (can_call<typename std::remove_reference<_To>::type>(declval<Func>())) can_call()
  constexpr auto can_call() ->
              ^~~~~~~~
  dd.cc:14:16: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above
  dd.cc: In instantiation of ‘auto detail::can_call<int>’:
  dd.cc:15:14:   required by substitution of ‘template<class Func, class T> constexpr decltype (can_call<typename std::remove_reference<_To>::type>(declval<Func>())) can_call() [with Func = foo; T = int]’
  dd.cc:26:48:   required from here
  dd.cc:10:10: error: ‘auto detail::can_call<int>’ has incomplete type
      auto can_call = hana::is_valid([](auto &&f) -> decltype(f.template operator()<T>()) { });
          ^~~~~~~~
  dd.cc:26:48: error: no matching function for call to ‘can_call<foo, int>()’
      std::cout << "int: " << can_call<foo, int>() << std::endl;
                                              ^
  dd.cc:14:16: note: candidate: template<class Func, class T> constexpr decltype (can_call<typename std::remove_reference<_To>::type>(declval<Func>())) can_call()
  constexpr auto can_call() ->
              ^~~~~~~~
  dd.cc:14:16: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above
  ```

It seems to not like my use of `hana::is_valid()` to determine whether the specified operator exists. However, I think the way I'm using it is consistent with its intended use.

Is this a bug in gcc, a more lenient implementation in contemporary clang versions, or did I implement this type of check incorrectly? It seems like this is definitely within Hana's wheelhouse; I'm just trying to wrap my head around its new model of `constexpr` metaprogramming.

Comment: FWIW, you seem to be using `hana::is_valid` correctly, and I would be tempted to say it's a compiler bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround that uses a struct "functor" instead of a lambda and an extra layer of indirection for the type of the `is_valid` instance to appease gcc.

```cpp
namespace detail 
{
    template <typename T>
    struct check_can_call { 
      template <typename F>
      constexpr auto operator()(F&& f) -> 
        decltype(f.template operator()<T>()) { }
    };

    template <typename T>
    using is_call_valid = decltype(hana::is_valid(check_can_call<T>{}));

    template <typename T>
    constexpr is_call_valid<T> can_call{};
}
```