# What is the advantage of Hana's type_c-and-declval dance when querying whether a SFINAE-friendly expression is valid?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae, boost-hana

On the one hand, the function [`boost::hana::is_valid`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1type.html#a2d2e7e08e284f7e0bd1bd9c3ad0e0a2b) is presented as follows

> Checks whether a SFINAE-friendly expression is valid.
>
> Given a SFINAE-friendly function, `is_valid` returns whether the function call is valid with the given arguments. Specifically, given a function `f` and arguments `args...`,
>
> ```
> is_valid(f, args...) == whether f(args...) is valid
> ```
>
> The result is returned as a compile-time `Logical`.

and an example of the usage accompanies it (from the same linked page):

```cpp
    struct Person { std::string name; };
    auto has_name = hana::is_valid([](auto&& p) -> decltype((void)p.name) { });
 
    Person joe{"Joe"};
    static_assert(has_name(joe), "");
    static_assert(!has_name(1), "");
```

where we see that the lambda fed to `is_valid` is in turn fed with the actual object that we feed to `has_name`.

On the other hand, the book [C++ Templates - The Complete Guide](http://www.tmplbook.com/) presents a very similar solution (and indeed the authors cite [Boost.Hana](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/) and [Loius Dionne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/627587/louis-dionne)), which I omit for now the details of. This solution, however, is used in a slightly different way:

```cpp
constexpr auto hasFirst = isValid([](auto x) -> decltype((void)valueT(x).first) {});
static_assert(!hasFirst(type<int>));
struct S { int first; };
static_assert(hasFirst(type<S>));
```

The above assumes the existence of `valueT` and `type` defined/declared below

```
template<typename T>
struct TypeT {
  using Type = T;
};

template<typename T>
constexpr auto type = TypeT<T>{};

template<typename T>
T valueT(TypeT<T>);
```

Now, if I understand correctly, `valueT` and `type` correspond roughly to [`boost::hana::traits::declval`](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/998033e9dba8c82e3c9496c274a3ad1acf4a2f36/include/boost/hana/traits.hpp#L213) and [`boost::hana::type_c`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1type.html#ae35139e732c4b75e91061513cf445628), so the example from the book should map to the following

```cpp
constexpr auto hasFirstH = is_valid([](auto x) -> decltype((void)traits::declval(x).first) {});
static_assert(!hasFirst(hana::type_c<int>));
struct S { int first; };
static_assert(hasFirst(hana::type_c<S>));
```

But what is the advantage of this?

In [this answer from Louis Dionne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35419693/5825294) I initially understood that it's a matter of taste, but then I thought that might be the case *for that specific scenario* and not in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing the question, I've searched more an more (to put relevant links in it, mainly), and I eventually did find the answer in the documentation of Boost.Hana at [Boost.Hana > User Manual > Introspection > Checking expression validity > Non-static members](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/index.html#tutorial-introspection-is_valid-non_static): the use of `hana::type_c` to wrap a type `T` in an object (not of type `T`, but of type `hana::type<T>`!) and `hana::declval` to unwrap it is useful to write those type traits when there's no object around.